# Do each java program requires each jvm to run?

Tags: java

Consider, I have a simple java program to add 2 numbers. If I run this program in 2 different terminals, in how many JVMs do they run?

Comment: Is this an exam question? If so show what parts of your research are unclear(actually either way). I.e. what you've read so far and what points that made and why they didn't make sense

Comment: How many times to you invoke the `java` command?

Comment: I undergo a training process, in which I was asked this question.

Comment: @HotLicks 2 times I invoke java command..

Comment: And what does the `java` command do?  It creates a JVM and causes the named Java program to be executed in it.

Comment: Every time you run a command (other than one built-in to the shell), you create a new process.  This is true of all applications, not just Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one has its own JVM instance. That should be obvious to you because the `java` command is not a system service.

Comment: There are "server" versions of Java where the JVM is essentially shared among multiple "independent" Java processes, but that's a special case, and I don't think the `java` command per se is used to start a process in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, unless you run multiple programs together and use a wrapper that starts each program in a different thread, as you can have multiple threads running within one JVM.